# Regexp: can't find right expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all the matches of string like:

```
{{ <text | default('<text or empty space>') }}
```

so a pattern where {{ | default('') }} are always present, for instance:

```
{{ text1 | default('default for text1 value') }}
```

and I need to match many of those patterns in the same line. I'm trying with (see [here](https://jsbin.com/hiveqeloca/edit?js,console))

```
[\{]{2} (.*) [|]{1} default(.*) [\}]{2}
```

but it's not getting the right matches (just one for 2 expressions). Any help?

Comment: Use lazy `.*?` patterns inside and remove `{1}`. And pass `"g"`  modifier to the regex constructor (better use a regex literal). See https://jsbin.com/mumuhoxidi/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `.*` part is greedy and matches as many symbols as it can. You may use a lazy version `.*?`, but also you need a `g` global modifier to make the regex engine match multiple times. Also, I suggest using a regex literal notation since the regex is static, and is not built from variables.

```
var reg = /\{{2} (.*?) \| default(.*?) \}{2}/g;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT9dW4/1)

```js
var reg = /\{{2} (.*?) \| default(.*?) \}{2}/g;

var text = "{{ text1 | default('text1 default') }} {{ text2 | default('text2 default') }}"

console.log(text.match(reg));
```

NOTE: You will need the `RegExp#exec` in a loop to get all captured texts.

Another note: if your input might have something like `{{ text}}` before the text you need, the `.*?` will act greedily. You will need to replacer all `.*?` with `(?:(?!\}{2}).)*` tempered greedy token. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT9dW4/3).